# Web server keeps using an old .js-file even after it have been removed/altered

Tags: javascript, ubuntu-16.04, lamp

I am using a LAMP stack web server running on Ubuntu 16.04. In my web root directory `/public/` I have a few files, but the two important ones concerning my problem are:

- `index.html`
- `main.build.js`

The web page is a single page application. `index.html` "opens up" the SPA via the `main.build.js`, which contains the whole SPA. However, after I made changes to the `main.build.js` the changes does **not** apply to the webpage's `main.build.js`.

What I've tried:

- Tried multiple browsers
- I have tried clearing the cache & cookies of my browser(s)
- Opening up the main.build.js that I made changes to make sure they were there (and they were)
- Deleting the main.build.js completely (but it still shows up on the webpage!!!)
- Restarting Apache
- Restarting the computer

Index.html:

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>BiggerWe (Alpha)</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700|Material+Icons' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
    </div>
    <script src="main.build.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any tips are welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [answered question](https://community.bitnami.com/t/stop-cache-completely/24819/3) you need to disable the PageSpeed features of the LMAP Stack and maybe the OPCache feature in `php.ini` by setting  `opcache.enable` from `1` to `0`

Comment: Thank you, this fixed my issue!